# How to get current stack trace in native code in Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: android, ios, c, xamarin.forms, stack-trace

We have a Xamarin.Forms application that has a native C library linked to it. We have both Android and iOS versions of the app. We need to print the **current stack trace** in the middle of the code execution in the native C library and write it to a file. This is not an exception situation, but it needs to be done in the middle of normally running application code. So, how do we get **the current call stack in the C code**? (We are not interested in the call stack of C# code.)

Comment: Could you provide some relevant code?

Comment: Here's the GitHub repository: https://github.com/hyvanmielenpelit/GnollHack
The place where we want to write the stack trace is here: https://github.com/hyvanmielenpelit/GnollHack/blob/87f0a79277b2ac6dbcaedd410faa61f200cdceec/src/files.c#L4086